# Regular expression in asp.net, containing either two fixed alphabets(D and DQ) or any two numbers

Tags: regex

I want to validate a text box (with max length 2) to contain only these 3 set of values.
(i)  00-99
(ii) Q
(iii) DQ

Invalid values are 1Q, 2D, QD, QQ, DD,etc etc

Comment: so basically 2 digits, the letter Q and the letter DQ ??

Comment: yes,either 2 digits or the letter Q or DQ in this order, not QD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright you can use the following it will check for what you asked for its very simple and primitive regix but will work:

`\d{2}|DQ|Q`

If you want to better understand regular expressions the following might help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

You can also use:
http://myregextester.com/index.php
As a tool to test your regix.

Hope that helps

Comment: It works. Thanks for your help and the links you shared were also helpful.